# How I can read an item through keys in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my attempt but it returns undefined but I've figured this can't be done without having the keys as `.child(keys)` or something of that nature.

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://users.firebaseio.com/");
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var users = snapshot.val();
  console.log("snap: " + snapshot.val());
  console.log("username: " + users.username);
  console.log("username: " + users.email);
});
```

Here's my firebase json text. I want to read email lastname and username through many keys not just per key.

```html
"users": {
  "6179eb29-9691-4828-be5a-28a94e84703b": {
    "-KLWoGzjymD0Sgvf5Rcs": {
      "email": "jaycarter@gmail.com",
      "lastname": "cater",
      "username": "jay"
    }
  },
  "6a210785-0a73-4c83-b3e1-d3828f9d8a3b": {
    "-KLqMiLTB71dTh7PrVpL": {
      "email": "k@gmail.com",
      "lastname": "john",
      "username": "smith"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey muzi, let me know if my answer helped you or if you still have any doubts. thanks.

Comment: i was able to do it with .child(keys) look at the answer below.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
taskref.onAuth(function(authData) {
      taskref
        .child("users")
        .child(authData.uid)
        .child("task")
        .orderByChild('date')
        .on('value', function(snapshot) {
          $scope.list = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            //  $scope.list = $scope.list.concat(child.val());
            $scope.list.splice(0, 0, child.val());
            console.log($scope.list);
          });

          $scope.taskKeys = function() {
            return Object.keys($scope.list);
          }

          $scope.complete = function(key) {
            taskref.child("users")
              .child(authData.uid)
              .child('task')
              .child(key)
              .set({
                status: true
              });
          }

        });
```

Comment: i answered this question, so by using  "Object.keys" so that i can be able to pass the specific key to my function then pass to my child node.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your firebase project anywhere.
I think you must use like this .

```
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "your_api_key",
  authDomain: "project-0000000000000000.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-0000000000000000.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "project-0000000000000000.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref= firebase.database().ref();
ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
var users = snapshot.val();
console.log("snap: " + snapshot.val());
console.log("username: " + users.username);
console.log("username: " + users.email);
});
</script>
```

Comment: i actually wanted to find out if this could be done how to read through child('keys')   on ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot)

Comment: Not clear to me...
Can you please explain a bit more..?

Comment: is it possible to read through name from ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child('name'); without having to provide key value pairs like .child("-KLWoGzjymD0Sgvf5Rcs") when calling retrieving a name.

Comment: according to your need you can get that object just using this _ref.child("users").child("6179eb29-9691-4828-be5a-28a94e84703b");_

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `orderByChild` combined with `equalTo`.

```
ref.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo("smith").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var users = snapshot.val();
  console.log("snap: " + snapshot.val());
  //loop over the found results
  snapshot.forEach(function(user){
      console.log(user);
  });
});
```

In your snippet you are initializing your ref using the legacy sdk. New firebase sdk has changed it a little bit.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref= firebase.database().ref();
```

Also, keep in mind that **you wont be able to use multiple `orderByChild` to query for multiple child parameters**. In this case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase) will give you some ideias on how to work on it.